# How can I drawText using canvaskit with word-break as normal?

Tags: canvas, skia, canvaskit

When we use canvaskit to drawText it draws text which is similar to the css `word-break: break-word;` i.e. it sub-wraps the word.

How can we disable it so that canvaskit draws the text similar to `word-break: normal` style.